# Power Bi aggregation by date

Tags: powerbi

I'm beginning with Power BI.

From my data source ( direct query ) I have rows with something like date - value.

I need aggregate results by month and year and with direct query it's not possible to create a calendar table.

What should I do in this case ? All solutions I've read need a calendar table than in this case ( direct query ) is not possible.

Thank you

Comment: Can you not add calculated columns in the direct query mode?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it now.

Comment: If you can't add a calendar dataset in your PowerBI, you can maybe create it as a table (or view) in your source database. (or in your SSAS Cube if you use one)